# Proprietary Software + GPL: A case study with OctaneRender and Blender

Tags: gpl, law, proprietary-code

**Background:**

I currently stumbled across an interesting case of a combination between a proprietary software and a GPL software, which I am trying to understand: There is the GPL software Blender - a well-known 3D creation software. Then there is a proprietary render engine OctaneRender developed by OTOY. OTOY distributes a modified version of Blender, the "Blender - OctaneRender edition". OTOY claims that this constellation is GPL compatible with the following reasoning:

> To conform to GPL rules, the OctaneRender® for Blender® plugin consists of two parts:
>
> - OctaneServer®
> - The full Blender – OctaneRender edition®
>
> OctaneServer® is the server for getting the TCP/IP render-commands and scene data from the client, rendering the scene, and returning the rendered image to the client.
>
> The Blender – OctaneRender® edition is the special compilation of Blender®, which includes the internal OctaneRender® module. The module collects the Blender® scene data and communicates with the OctaneServer® as the client by sending the data to the server, getting the rendered image from it, and showing that image to you.
>
> Such a way GPL is not violated by OctaneRender® for Blender Plugin: as the source-code of Blender – OctaneRender® edition (which is under GPL) is available for users of the Plugin, and the source-code of Otoy‘s proprietary closed-sourced OctaneServer® does not need to be published, as OctaneServer® is not linked to Blender and works with render-clients through TCP/IP communication.

**Interpretation - Agree or Disagree:**

**Agrees:** I understand, that this can be interpreted as GPL compatible in the sense that - using the wording of the Free Software Foundation - both the closed-source OctaneServer and the "Blender - OctaneRender edition" developed by OTOY communicate ["at arms length"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem) over a well-known [socket / communication protocol](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation). They could, thus, be considered a [mere aggregation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation).

**Disagrees:** On the other hand, however, both Blender and OctaneServer exchange what could be considered ["complex internal data structures"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation): the Blender scene data. (as stated in the quote above). That, in turn, would make them a [single, combined work](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation) according to Free Software Foundation.

**Questions:**

1. Which of my interpretations is correct?
2. If that constellation is fine, why is OTOY using a completely own Blender version when they could - technically - also just distribute a Blender plugin instead? I know, your answer might be "ask OTOY", but I am interested in: Do you see any legal reasons that would make it more reasonable to modify the complete software instead if using a plugin (which itself, would be a derived work of Blender)?

Comment: Note that this is nothing special nor new. NVidia's Linux drivers consist(ed) of a GPL'd, open source "shim" that communicates with the proprietary driver module. NDISWrapper was a Linux module that allowed proprietary Windows networking drivers to be loaded into the Linux kernel: NDIS is a standardized API for writing Windows networking drivers, so the driver simply implemented a binary compatible ABI in Linux. An early implementation of NTFS for Linux was implemented by loading the `ntfs.sys` driver from Windows into the Linux kernel. There were open source GPL patches to GCC that allowed …

Comment: … saving intermediate stages of the compilation to files in a standardized format and reading them back, which then allowed proprietary optimizers to read those files, perform optimizations, write back the optimized result, and resume compilation. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, just naming other examples doesn't help too much to understand the details of GPL - and that is, what my question aims at. (Sorry, if I wasn't clear enough about that). However, it would be helpful if you could create a separate answer that explains - with reference to GPL text - why those two are GPL compliant and how that compares to the case I cited.

Comment: In every single one of those case, there was never a trial, so nobody has ever determined whether or not those case are or are not GPL-compliant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question already contains the relevant analysis, and without knowing details about their protocol there's nothing to add here. So this is a case where the software *could* be compliant, and is not obviously non-compliant. Ultimately, this is not for the FSF or me but for a court to decide. So we'll never know unless and until a Blender copyright holder sues OTOY. Due to the way how the GPL is structured, only copyright holders but not end users have standing to enforce the GPL.

As to why the software is distributed as a bundle rather than a plugin: there's probably no licensing reason for this. However, there might be non-licensing reasons such as ease of installation or lock-in effects desired by the vendor. There could also be technical reasons, e.g. if the necessary integration is not possible using only a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your input and confirming that both of my interpretations are valid. I will still keep this question as "unanswered" for now to see, if other opinions or insights come in.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you wrote in your answer that we will never know “unless and until **a Blender copyright holder sues OTOY**”. Isn’t the danger of being sued a bit bigger? Could not actually anybody who gets into possession of the modified Blender version sue OTOY to release their source code of the render engine with the argument that it falls under the GPL? (Just trying to understand what legal consequences their could be and if the outspoken “OK” from the Blender copyright holders would suffice to protect against any law suits in that case)

Comment: @reg.cs The GPL does not contain a right for end users to receive the source code, but instead requires those who distribute the software in original or modified form to also offer the source code. That ends up having the same effect, except that it's a contract between the copyright holders and those who distribute the software. The end user is not party to this contract, and therefore has no standing to sue. The next generation of copyleft licenses is trying to fix this by explicitly including all recipients as third-party beneficiaries.

Comment: ah, that is interesting! Could you point me to some source or in the best case to the GPL text part were this can be inferred from? And when you talk about next generation copyleft licenses, are there any specific ones (the names would be enough, so that I can google myself)?

Comment: @reg.cs The GPL gives permissions to recipients subject to conditions. GPLv2 section 3: “You may copy and distribute the Program … in object code or executable form … provided that you also … accompany it with the … source code”. GPLv3 section 6: “You may convey a covered work in object code form … provided that you also convey the … Corresponding Source”. As “next-gen” licenses, I consider [copyleft-next](https://github.com/copyleft-next/copyleft-next/) and the [Cryptographic Autonomy License](https://opensource.org/licenses/CAL-1.0) to contain interesting improvements over the GPL.

Comment: I now found the following statement, which - in my understanding - contradicts your previous statement: [Section 2 (of the GPL) says that modified versions you distribute must be licensed **to all third parties** under the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#TheGPLSaysModifiedVersions). That is, there is a contract (a license agreement) between any third party and OTOY. So, the end user receiving the modified version is a party in a GPL license agreement and has, thus, a standing to sue the distributer of the modified version to provide the source of all parts of the work.

Comment: @reg.cs Yes, there's a GPL between Blender→OTOY and OTOY→End User. But the GPL only imposes conditions on the recipient, not on the licensor. The end user cannot sue if OTOY is violating obligations from the “Blender→OTOY” contract. If a licensee violates the conditions of the license, that's a copyright violation and usually only the copyright holder is entitled to sue for this.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it some further thought and it totally makes sense. I would like to add one example though where [a court decided differently in France and allowed a lawsuit filed by an end user](https://fsffrance.org/news/article2009-09-22.en.html). Anyway, that's a special case I guess. Would you consider to add a short explanation about the issue of who can sue in your answer? I think that would help others as well. Then I would also accept your response, since it basically fully answers everything I wanted to know.

Comment: @reg.cs I added a short sentence about standing, but feel that detailed discussion would be out of scope of this Q&A. Maybe if you ask a separate question about this, someone can write a more detailed answer. It's interesting that the French court inferred a third party beneficiary, but it's not in the text of the license so that interpretation cannot be relied on. That interpretation would seem to violate the *contra proferentem* principle, except maybe if the end user is a Consumer.

Comment: I am totally fine with this small sentence. Just think, that this is relevant since it essentially states: If the copyright owner is okay with it, you might risk to do it. I wasn’t aware of that detail and others might be in the same situation. With regard to France you are right - but it exemplifies that even such basic things of standing and privity can be interpreted on different ways for the GPL.

Comment: I agree that the question of third-party rights is too complex for a comment field, but I'd also recommend a new question, as I *do* have some useful light to shed, from an excellent legal talk given at FOSDEM a few years back.